# Randomize HTML string output

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, random

```
<?php 
    $random1 = '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Why join the navy<BR />if you can be a pirate.</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>';
    $random2 = '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem2</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>';
    $random3 = '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem3</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>';
    echo(rand($random1, $random2, $random3));
?>
```

So I've written the code above. I want my code to randomize the quote that appears. Would there be an user-friendly way of implementing this in a website?

I'm building a website in Wordpress and I was wondering if Wordpress (or PHP) had an easier method of randomizing output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternatively, you could define an array which contains HTML strings and then use an `array_rand()` function to get a random entry/element. Example:

```
// set of elements with random quotes
$quotes = array(
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Why join the navy<BR />if you can be a pirate.</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem2</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem3</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
);

// apply array_rand function
echo $quotes[array_rand($quotes)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$random = array();

$random[] = '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Why join the navy<BR />if you can be a pirate.</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>';
$random[] = '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem2</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>';
$random[] = '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem3</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>';

shuffle($random);

foreach($random as $quote)
{
    echo $quote;
}
```

Comment: This would randomize the array for sure. But display all of the elements

Comment: True I misread the question a bit. Could use $random[0] for a random quote.

Comment: That, or if you really wish to use a foreach (which I personally wouldn't) use `break;` after the first iteration so the loop does not repeat

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
<?php 
$quotes = array(
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Why join the navy<BR />if you can be a pirate.</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem2</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem3</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>'
);

echo($quotes[mt_rand(0, (count($quotes) - 1))]);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this clean and simply:

```
$quotes = array(
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Why join the navy<BR />if you can be a pirate.</h2>    <h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem2</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
    '<p>Quotes van de fans:</p><h2>Lorem3</h2><h3>Steve jobs</h3>',
);

echo $quotes[rand(0,2)]; // 0-2 (Since array's start on 0)
```

Comment: What if the array expands?